# Invoice Stylesheet Spacing

Tags: gnucash

I'm trying to set up my invoice style in GnuCash. I've created a new stylesheet from within GnuCash but I need to make some changes to the stylesheet that aren't covered by the options within GnuCash so I'm going to have to edit the stylesheet directly. Unfortunately, I can't find it! I've given it a distinctive name within GnuCash, but I've done a complete search of my filesystem and can't find it anywhere. Does GnuCash give it a different name? How do I find the file to modify it?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the forum](https://lists.gnucash.org/pipermail/gnucash-user/2015-August/061431.html), they're stored in c:\users\.gnucash\stylesheets-2.0